# Routing a polymorphic model with multiple nests in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This might be a tough one

I have a site which is using a polymorphic comments model.

Lets say the first model is library, and the second is book

so we have, library/1/book/63/

how do I route it so comments are then library/1/book/63/comments/1 ?

Thanks,

Elliot

update: looking for code for routes.rb file

Comment: Are you looking for code for the routes.rb file? Or code to generate a URL? Or both?

Comment: code for the routes.rb file :)

Comment: its funny I actually just watched your railscast about polymorphic rails - which got me to now. You're the man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just nest them:

```
map.resources :libraries do |library|
    library.resources :books do |book|
       book.resources :comments
    end
end
```

It may be confusing, but the polymorphic aspect of the data model is independent of the routes.

To call them via named routes, for a comment you'll need to provide a library and a book, even if it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.resources :libraries do |library|
    library.resources :books, :has_many=>[:comments]
end
```